# Do you need 2 instances of Azure websites for SLA like Web Roles?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

On cloud services web roles you must create at least 2 instances to get Azure's 99.95% SLA because when they do updates to the servers' OS etc, Azure will need to restart the machines (one at a time). This is well documented and you will be shouted at by the portal when running a one instance web role for doing this.

With Azure websites you don't get such warnings and I cannot find any documentation suggesting 2 instances for the 99.9% SLA. However, I also can't find any documentation saying that you *don't* need 2 instances for this SLA.

So which is it? Do I need 2 instances for Azure websites' SLA like web roles or is that a thing of the past?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A developer on the Azure Websites team has [replied here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29527802/325251) that

> the SLA for any Azure Website on the Basic or Standard tier is 99.95%
>
> Just having one instance of the site is enough

Comment: Thanks for finally answering this important question. FYI I have now been running one instance websites without any signs of downtime since January 2015

Answer (score 5):

You can download the Azure Web Sites SLA document here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/

It does not state that you need 2 instances to get the 99.9% SLA but clearly state that the Free and Shared Web Site Tiers are not covered by this SLA.

Comment: I read that when I was researching. The thing that bothers me is that it although it doesn't state that you do need two instances for the SLA it doesn't state you *don't* either. Given how much emphasis azure put on needing two web role instances I would have thought they would explicitly state that it doesn't apply to websites. Hence the confusion :(

Answer (score -1):

We guarantee that Web Apps, Mobile Apps, Logic Apps, and API Apps running in a customer subscription will be available 99.9% of the time, with a 99.95% SLA provided when multiple instances and traffic manager are used. No SLA is provided for Apps or sites under either the Free or Shared tiers.

Comment: Where is the 99.9% for 1 instance and 99.95% for multiple instances, statement is mentioned on the Azure documentation? It just says
here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/app-service/v1_4/

We guarantee that Apps running in a customer subscription will be available 99.95% of the time. No SLA is provided for Apps under either the Free or Shared tiers.