# What is the SLA for a single instance VM on Basic / Standard tier of Azure Website

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

[This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587234/do-you-need-2-instances-of-azure-websites-for-sla-like-web-roles) differently last year but it has not received an authoritative answer.

[The updated SLA](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/) says - "We guarantee that all websites running in a customer subscription will respond to client requests 99.95% of the time. No SLA is provided for Websites under either the Free or Shared tiers."

Does this unambiguously mean that SLA for a single instance VM on Basic / Standard tier of Azure Website is 99.95%? If not, what is the assurance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the SLA for any Azure Website on the Basic or Standard tier is 99.95%

Just having one instance of the site is enough

Comment: 99.95% of 744 hrs is approximately 25 minutes. So, for a given month, the maximum time that the App Service might go down is approximately 25 minutes. Is there a chance that the site might go down for 25 minutes at once in a month? I understand that might be a worst case. But, If that is the case, how do we (as a developer) know that my site is down and I can show a "Site under maintenance" page to my visitors?

Comment: There are steps you can take to improve your SLA. Deploy copies of your site to multiple regions, and use the Azure Traffic Manager to route requests to all of them. Or if you don't want to pay extra for the improved up time, create a cheap static site somewhere (you might be able to use blob storage for this, but I'm not sure) with the "site under maintenance" sign, and use the Traffic Manager in Failover mode to route requests to your "maintenance" site instead of your primary site.  That way customers will get rerouted without you having to even know about your site being down.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from mvark is contradictory with what the SLA page states, where it clearly says you need multiple instances and a traffic manager for 99.95%:

> We guarantee that Web Apps, Mobile Apps, Logic Apps, and API Apps running in a customer subscription will be available 99.9% of the time, with a 99.95% SLA provided when multiple instances and traffic manager are used. No SLA is provided for Apps or sites under either the Free or Shared tiers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I must have missed the *add a comment* link! I will add the comment and delete the answer.

Comment: Oh. I don't have sufficient reputation to comment, maybe that's why.